# Spinner Android onItemSelected just select the last item of the list

Tags: android, spinner

I populate a spinner from this JSON :

```
[
    {
        "vhc_name": "",
        "vhc_login": "",
        "vhc_password": ""
    },
    {
        "vhc_name": "Tél de Pan-K",
        "vhc_login": "178143p",
        "vhc_password": "kaspersky"
    },
    {
        "vhc_name": "toto",
        "vhc_login": "215058k",
        "vhc_password": "azertyu"
    },
    {
        "vhc_name": "azertyuiop",
        "vhc_login": "221589a",
        "vhc_password": "azertyu"
    }
]
```

It works fine but when I use `setOnItemSelectedListener` on my spinner it just retrieve the data of the last JSONObject :

```
{
    "vhc_name": "azertyuiop",
    "vhc_login": "221589a",
    "vhc_password": "azertyu"
}
```

Any idea where does it come from ?

Here's my code :

```
private static final String TAG_LOGIN = "vhc_login";
private static final String TAG_PWD = "vhc_password";

         String readFeed = readFeed();
// Display the list of the user's devices
ArrayList<Devices> devices = new ArrayList<Devices>();
// use this array to populate myDevicesSpinner
ArrayList<String> devicesNames = new ArrayList<String>();

try {

  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readFeed); // Method which parse the JSON Data


  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Devices device = new Devices();
    device.setName(jsonObject.optString(TAG_NAME));
    devices.add(device);
    devicesNames.add(jsonObject.optString(TAG_NAME));

   }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myDevicesSpinner);
mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, devicesNames));
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
Devices tmp_device = devices.get(i);
        pwd = tmp_device.getPassword();
        Log.d("testoui",pwd);
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

} 
});
```

The log "ouioui" shows :

```
11:41:08.539    9081    com.JeLocalisetrackerApp.view   DEBUG   ouioui  kaspersky
11:41:08.539    9081    com.JeLocalisetrackerApp.view   DEBUG   ouioui  azertyu
11:41:08.539    9081    com.JeLocalisetrackerApp.view   DEBUG   ouioui  azertyu
```

The log "ouiouii" shows :

```
11:41:08.539    9081    com.JeLocalisetrackerApp.view   VERBOSE ouiouii 178143p
11:41:08.539    9081    com.JeLocalisetrackerApp.view   VERBOSE ouiouii 215058k
11:41:08.539    9081    com.JeLocalisetrackerApp.view   VERBOSE ouiouii 221589a
```

The log "ouiouioui" shows :

```
11:41:08.585        9081    com.JeLocalisetrackerApp.view   VERBOSE ouiouioui   azertyu
```

The log "ouiouiouii" shows :

```
11:41:08.585        9081    com.JeLocalisetrackerApp.view   VERBOSE ouiouiouii  221589a
```

Everytime I select a different device in the spinner the log displays the last message "ouiouioui" and "ouiouiouii" Why ? How can I retrieve the value of each JSONObject in the onItemSelected ?

My class Devices goes like this :

```
public class Devices {

 String name;
 String logindevice;
 String passworddevice;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getLogin() {
    return logindevice;
}
public void setLogin(String logindevice) {
    this.logindevice = logindevice;
}    

public String getPassword() {
    return passworddevice;
}
public void setPassword(String passworddevice) {
    this.passworddevice = passworddevice;
}
}
```

Comment: You do a `for` loop and assign some values to the `pwd` and `id` variables(and at the end of the `for` loop those variables will point to the last value of the loop) and then read those in the `OnItemSelectedListener` callback. What do you expect to happen from this logic?

Comment: Yeah you right I thought that the string will take all the values but I've never been so wrong sorry. Any idea of how to correct this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. To get the device name from the `deviceNames` list simply use `((ArrayAdapter<String>)mySpinner.getAdapter().getItem(position)`

Comment: The spinner displays only the names of the devices. In my JSON each name have a login and a password when the user selects a deviceName I want to retrieve both login & password from this JSONObject. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well your `device` list has a connection to the `deviceNames` list so you could simply do `Devices dvc = devices.get(position);`. I'm assuming that the `Devices` object holds the desired data.

Comment: Devices is just a public class. public class Devices {
    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
Sorry if I'm dumb :/.

Comment: Why do you use it then? The `position` parameter could be used to retrieve the `JSONObject` from the `jsonArray`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your edited answer. Is there a simple solution to save the corresponding login & password of the device selected ? Can you show me how do I implement it in my code ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing your onItemSelectedListener to something like i've implemented:

```
category_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {

                        String item_selected = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)+"";//---------------This ***+""*** works as a toString() method
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                    }
                });
```

Also, i dont understand why are you setting the selection, when the your action will definitely fire this onItemSelected method. This is why you have implemented `OnItemSelectedListener`. You dont have to set the selection inside onItemSelected.

`public abstract void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

where,

`parent = The AdapterView where the selection happened`

`view = The view within the AdapterView that was clicked`

`position = The position of the view in the adapter`

`id = The row id of the item that is selected`

Sorry i didn't read your comment section. You want username and password of the devicename selected from spinner, so simply you do this `Devices tmp_device = devices.get(int position);` in OnItemSelected() and do whatever you want with this `Devices` object you got on selection.

Comment: I don't understand this sorry. arg0 is the deviceName & arg2 is the password ? And "+ """ what's that for ? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: No bro... you are wrong. Please check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html Just a minute.I am helping you clear your misconception.

Comment: @ThomasPancani Are you clear with the concept of spinner now ??

Comment: Devices is a class I've got an error "unexpected type required: value found: class" and what is int position ? How does it know that it's referring to the login & password of the device selected ? Still, thank you for your help.

Comment: @ThomasPancani See it goes like this. The data within both the ArrayLists are filled at a same time, hence we can do like, when the data with "abc" deviceName is selected, return the object related to deviceName "abc". We know that the position of "abc" in deviceNames and in Devices will be the same. So we directly return the Devices object(that is what you are expecting) through, `Devices tmp_device = devices.get(position);` where position is the integer argument of OnItemSelected() method. The integer argument signifies position of the view which was selected.

Comment: So Devices tmp_device = devices.get(position); will return "vhc_name": "toto",
        "vhc_login": "215058k",
        "vhc_password": "azertyu"
If the user selects toto in the spinner ? And if i want both "vhc_login" & "vhc_password" saved in two different strings to use those ID after in my code ?

Comment: `will return "vhc_name": "toto", "vhc_login": "215058k", "vhc_password": "azertyu" If the user selects toto in the spinner ?` answer is: yes. And after that to get the variables of that Devices object, hope, you must have created the getter methods like `get_vhc_name()`, `get_vhc_login()`, `get_vhc_password()` in your Devices class.

Comment: Yes I've got this     `public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;` in my Devices class is that correct ?
So i did :  `Devices tmp_device = devices.get(i);
            pwd = tmp_device.setName(TAG_PWD);`
But the onItemSelected is void so it says "incompatible types". How can I correct that ? Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry I've got this     `public String getName() {
        return name;
    }`
and `pwd = tmp_device.getName();` displays the device name only which is normal because I ask for it but how can I ask for the login & password ?

Comment: Dear, your class Devices should have all the three fields name, login and password. Then you just create constructor of that class as Devices(String tmp_name, String tmp_login, String tmp_password){...}

Comment: Dear, your class Devices should have all the three fields name, login and password. Then you just create constructor of that class as Devices(String tmp_name, String tmp_login, String tmp_password){...} and you need to pass all three values in `Devices device = new Devices(name, login, string);`

Comment: @ThomasPancani Also please update your corrected code. So that i may know where the problem is.

Comment: I've found the solution thanks for your great help ! I followed a tutorial for parsing JSON data and apparently I didn't understand it at all now it worked I simply use this line     `device.setPassword(jsonObject.optString(TAG_PWD));` in my for loop then it worked. You saved me !

Comment: @ThomasPancani Now you're on the right track. Now all you need is to do, `Devices device = new Devices(name, login, string);`.

Comment: This is what i was talking about. I took it another way, like create a class, inside it, creating constructor and getter methods. And then simply create object of that class by passing values during initialization. Well, Gud luck. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the tag for items by `setTag()`.
Then It will work